# dojox enhancedGrid override canEdit function

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

Im trying to override `canEdit(inCell, inRowIndex)` and to set disabled fields like `canEdit(3, 0);` so the row 0 and cell 3 is no longer editable. I using dojo 1.8.

I have a problem that either it doesnt work or it sets the full grid uneditable.

```
var index = grid.selection.selectedIndex;

grid.canEdit = function(inCell, inRowIndex) {
  console.log("inCell = " + inCell);
  if(inCell == 3)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
};

grid.canEdit(3, index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inCell variable is an object and not integer.
you should be using *inCell.index* or *inCell.layoutIndex* instead

```
grid.canEdit = function(inCell, inRowIndex) {
  console.log("inCell = ", inCell);
  if(inCell.index == 3)
    return false;
  else
    return true;
};
```